# Can anyone explain grothendiecks spiky point in the image?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

[image]

In this picture, at the bottom right we see a spiky object with infinity pointing up and $0.1.2.$ What is this object? Can anybody help?

Edit: it seems as if the points in the drawing are the maximal ideals of specZ[x]

Comment: What is the source of this image?  It looks like a variant of [Mumford's famous drawing of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/mumfords-treasure-map) but the arrows are an addition which indeed seems mysterious to me.

Comment: I *think* the arrows are supposed to depict the directions in the tangent spaces at each point?  But it's hard to be sure without more context.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/grothendiecks-functor-of-points